# Find the $1717$th term of the sequence of positive integers whose binary representation reads the same left to right as right to left.

Tags: number-theory, binary

The question is to find the number of $1$'s in the $1717$th term.

I solved it but my method is not elegant IMO and it goes like this.

Let the number of digits in one binary representation in this pattern be $x$. Let $f(x)$ be the amount of representations having $x$ digits.

Then $f(1)=f(2)=1$, $f(3)=f(4)=2$, $f(5)=f(6)=4=2^2, f(7)=f(8)=8=2^3 \cdots \cdots$

So, $2^n$ gives the amount of the binary representations with $2n+2$ and $2n+1$ digits.

And $1+1+2+2+\cdots 2^n+2^n=2(2^{n+1}-1)$ gives the total number of the binary representations from $1$-digit representation to $2n$-digit representations.

Hence, $2(2^{n+1}-1)=1717$, so $512\le 2^{n+1}=859.5\le 1024$. That means $8\le n\le 9$.

Until $n=8$, there are altogether $2(2^9-1)=1022$ numbers, and until $n=9$ there are altogether $2046$ numbers.

So, for the $1717$th term, it corresponds to $n=9$. Since there are $1024$ terms in the case where $n=9$, which is corresponding to $512$ representations with $19$ and another $512$ representations with $20$ digits, the $1717$th term should have $20$ digits, and it is in fact the $1717-512-1022=183$th term starting from the first $20$-digit representation.

Then since every representation is symmetric, we only need to consider what is going on in the first 10 digits.

Since it must start with $1$, and for each digit, it can be either $0$ or $1$, the $k$ in $2^k<183, k\in \mathbb Z$ implies where the "highest" $1$ is other than the starting $1$.

Since $k=8$, it is 1 _ 1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _.

Then since $2^{k_1}<183-128$ that means $k_1=5$, the representation is 1 _ 1 _ _ 1 _ _ _ _.

Similarly, I finally got 1 _ 1 _ _ 1 1 _ 1 1. That means the $1717$th term will have $12$ $1$'s.

Ok now could anyone offer a more elegant method?

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a way of calculating exactly the first half of the binary representation knowing the place, in this case $1717$. If you create the sequence of numbers that give you only the first half you find this one: [A162751](http://oeis.org/A162751). There are some good properties about it, the most important one is that for $i \geq 2$ we have $a(2^i-1) = 2^{i-1}$. You could prove this by induction, having in mind that each "cycle" that we see in the sequence is just writing numbers with odd $0$ and $1$s in its binary representation first (which we know there is a particular power of $2$ of them) and after that the same repeated sequence but for ones with even number of $0$ and $1$. So you end up ending each cycle after a power of $2$, so it's natural to have a formula like the one before.

Now you can use this to obtain $a(1023) = 512$. We know the sequence of $512$ numbers after this one repeats, and we notice $1717$ is in the second half. We need to know where exactly it ends. You can see that the cycle repeats exactly in $2^i - 1 + 2^{i-1}$, in this case $i=10$ and it repeats in $1535 = 1023+512$, so $a(1535) = 512$. Until $1717$ the sequence just adds one, so $a(1717) = a(1535) + 1717-1535 = 512+182 = 694$. If you count the number of this number in binary ($1010110110$) you're counting the number of $1$ in the first half, so take that number, in this case six $1$, and double it to obtain $12$ ones.